# What would happen if you spin a straight wire in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Would the positive and negative charges line up on either end of the wire?  Or would it induce a current? Or would the wire be unaffected by the magnet?

This was deleted for being a homework question.  I'm not aware of any homework questions like this.  I thought this up in my own head. (I drew the diagram in a program called Biorender, which I use regularly.)

This IS a question about the underlying nature of physics.  The question I have is this, "If simply moving a straight wire through a field causes motional emf, why then does a loop of wire require an area and a certain angle to create a current?"  Why wouldn't moving a loop create a current if moving a straight wire creates a potential difference?  All of the explanations I can find out there separate the two concepts from each other.  "Because Lenz's law states..."  How are they tied together?  It's still a wire through a field. Physically, what happens to the charges when a loop moves through a field as opposed to when a straight wire moves through a field?  But before I can even get to how the two situations are the same or different, I had to clarify some things about how a current can be induced in a straight wire.

The following image was meant as the answer to my question, but Stack Exchange seemed to feel it went in the question.  Now it may not make sense why I needed an answer when the answer is below.  But that's why the answer is in the question itself in case anyone is confused about that.

[image]

Comment: It depends on many things like how you define your wire, and how you build your magnetic field. Furthermore, what makes you think that charges pile up in magnetic fields?

Comment: The reason why some people think of this as a homework question is because variations of this are being used as homework questions in undergrad physics studies. They are used as motivation to develop a mental model in which electromagnetic fields are seen as an integrated observer dependent phenomenon. In this case the moving wire is the observer of an electrostatic field.

Comment: This is a more advanced question than any question in my homework.  Neither my book nor my homework explain the connection between Lenz's law and motional emf.  They separate the concepts.

Comment: There are a bunch of homework questions on the internet.  I challenge anyone to find a spinning wire in a static magnetic field question.  A moving wire, yes.  A spinning wire, no.   I looked and looked before asking this.  Would the charge move up and down the wire?  Would it stay in the middle?  I honestly didn't know.  Maybe I'm just an idiot, and it's plainly obvious to everyone else, but there is no homework question that answers this.

Comment: And then even if the charges do separate, what happens when you put that same situation in a circuit?  None of these kinds of issues are mentioned in my physics book.

Answer (score 3):

The Lorentz force law says the force on a charge $q$ in the wire (e.g. an electron) is
$$\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v\times \vec B).$$
Charges rearrange until the net force on each charge is zero. Well, technically there will be a net force equal to the centripetal force, but in general it will have such a tiny effect that it can be neglected: verify this yourself as an exercise.

The magnetic force per unit charge is is $\omega r B$ inward where $\omega$ is the angular speed and $r$ is the radius, so the electric force per unit charge (i.e. the E-field) will be $\omega r B$, outward. This means the ends of the wire will be negatively charged relative to the center. There will be a potential difference between the center of the wire and either end, but none between the two ends.

Your other question about a loop moving through a magnetic field seems unrelated, but here is the answer. If you move a straight wire through a magnetic field, you get a non-zero emf. You can think of a rectangular loop as a combination of four pieces of wire. Each contributes an emf, but in directions that cancel when added. This is just like connecting two identical batteries in series, but in reverse polarity: the combination of the two batteries will have zero emf. As an exercise, consider a rectangular loop moving in a uniform field, and show that the emfs on opposite sides of the loop cancel.

Answer (score 0):

**Idealized problem**: the wire is infinitesimally small, so all (infinitesimally small) charged particles are spinning along the axis, and not around it, so the motion is effectively straight.
**Idealized solution**: no tangential velocity of charges = Lorentz force as if no spinning was done

**Real problem**: the wire does have finite radius and charges do somewhat spiral down the wire. Now the answer heavily depends on the orientation of the magnetic field.
If the field was parallel to the wire, and you assume that motion is highly symmetric about the axis of rotation (a literal spiral of electrons, like a srcew, even), all Lorentz force components would cancel out except for the usual one of charge moving up a wire, so you are back at the idealized case.
**Real (non) answer**: in any other configuration, the wire would wind up and do messy things that I can't simulate without the help of code

Comment: So the magnet would have an effect on the wire.  That's really where I was headed with this question.

Comment: well the picture completely invalidates my question, since "spinning" was not defined, and I made my wire spin on it's axis.
My guess is the magnet would induce currents so to resist the spinning, so assuming your spinning apparatus can win that, the wire would bend in a "C" pattern and mess around in that general shape. 
Furthermore, because your wire must be attached to something to pass current, it would be difficult to simulate such an idealized situation, you would end up with extra magnetic fluxes due to the 3D build of the spinning circuit etc etc

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to reconcile motional emf with Lenz's law.

Comment: I think it's better to be simulated. Too many things going on